# Jest : How to reset a manual mock

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am trying to check the console.log output in my tests ...

It's ok on the first test, but not on the second one... I guess it should be an issue with the mock function .. should it be reset ? 
I tried to use

```
jest.resetAllMocks()
```

but it raises an error..

here is my test code :

```
import Blog from '../../src/client/js/blog.js';
import mockAxios from "axios";

jest.mock('axios');

describe('client/blog', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log = jest.fn();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockAxios.delete.mockClear();
    console.log.mockClear();
  });

  it('set the DeletePostHandler', async function () {
    // WHEN
     ...
    jest.spyOn(window.location, 'assign').mockImplementation(url => console.log('resolved'))
    // WHEN
    await document.querySelector('#link_1').click();
    // THEN
    expect(mockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(console.log.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('resolved')
  });


  it('does not set the DeletePostHandler', async function () {
    // WHEN
    ...
    jest.spyOn(window.location, 'assign').mockImplementation(url => console.log('rejected'))
    // WHEN
    await document.querySelector('#link_1').click();
    // THEN
    expect(mockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(console.log.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('rejected')
  });

});
```

thanks for feedback

**UPDATE 1**

when I don't mock the console, I can check the correct output :

```
 PASS  tests/client/blog.spec.js
  client/blog
    ✓ set the DeletePostHandler (28ms)
    ✓ does not set the DeletePostHandler (4ms)

  console.log tests/client/blog.spec.js:26
    resolved

  console.log tests/client/blog.spec.js:43
    rejected

 PASS  tests/client/comment.spec.js
  client/comment
    ✓ test setup OK (2ms)

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
```

**UPDATE 2**

As recommended in @Yuri' comment, I gave up to console.log checking and uI pdated the specs and added some console.log to check outputs, I still cannot test correctly the second test...  as the window.location.assign mock does not reset correctly for the second test....

**/tests/client/blog.spec.js**

```
import Blog from '../../src/client/js/blog.js';
import mockAxios from "axios";

jest.mock('axios');

describe('client/blog', () => {

  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.spyOn(window.location, 'assign').mockImplementation(() => {});
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockAxios.delete.mockClear();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    // clean up after all tests
    window.location.assign.mockRestore()
  });

  it('set the DeletePostHandler', async function () {
    // WHEN
    const post = '<div class="posts"><div class="post">' +
      '<p>Today should be a great day to be alive!</p>' +
      '<div class="is-hidden">' +
      '<a id="link_1" class="delete-post" href="/admin/edit-post/1" data-post-id="1">delete<i class="is-hidden"></i></a>' +
      '</div></div>';
    document.body.innerHTML = post;
    Blog.pageReady('admin-index');
    // WHEN
    await document.querySelector('#link_1').click();
    // THEN
    expect(mockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(window.location.assign).toBeCalledWith('/admin?cache=false');
  });

  it('does not set the DeletePostHandler', async function () {
    // WHEN
    const post = '<div class="posts"><div class="post">' +
      '<p>Today should be a great day to be alive!</p>' +
      '<div class="is-hidden">' +
      '<a id="link_1" class="delete-post" href="/admin/edit-post/" data-post-id="">delete<i class="is-hidden"></i></a>' +
      '</div></div>';
    document.body.innerHTML = post;
    Blog.pageReady('admin-index');
    // WHEN
    await document.querySelector('#link_1').click();
    // THEN
    expect(mockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(window.location.assign).toBeCalledWith('/admin?cache=true');
  });
```

***mocks*/axios.j**s

```
export default {
  delete: jest.fn((url) => {
    if (url === '/api/v1/blog/1') {
        return Promise.resolve({
          data: {},
          status: 200,
          statusText: 'OK',
          headers: {}
        });
    } else {
      return Promise.reject({
        data: {},
        status: 400,
        statusText: 'Error',
        headers: {}
      });
    }
  })
};
```

**/client/blog.js**

```
  const deletePost = id => {
    axios.delete(`${API_BASE}/blog/${id}`, {
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
        data: null, // data null is necessary to pass the headers
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('AXIOS RESOLVED: ', result);
        console.log('GOING TO CALL window.location.assign with /admin?cache=false');
        window.location.assign('/admin?cache=false');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('AXIOS REJECTED: ', e);
        console.log('GOING TO CALL window.location.assign with /admin?cache=true');
        window.location.assign('/admin?cache=true');
      });
    };
```

**console**

```
console.log src/client/js/blog.js:12
    AXIOS RESOLVED:  { data: {}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {} }

  console.log src/client/js/blog.js:13
    GOING TO CALL window.location.assign with /admin?cache=false

  console.log src/client/js/blog.js:17
    AXIOS REJECTED:  { data: {}, status: 400, statusText: 'Error', headers: {} }

  console.log src/client/js/blog.js:18
    GOING TO CALL window.location.assign with /admin?cache=true

 PASS  tests/client/comment.spec.js



● client/blog › does not set the DeletePostHandler

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      "/admin?cache=true"
    as argument 1, but it was called with
      "/admin?cache=false".

      50 |     // THEN
      51 |     expect(mockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    > 52 |     expect(window.location.assign).toBeCalledWith('/admin?cache=true');
         |                                    ^
      53 |   });
      54 |
      55 | });

      at Object.toBeCalledWith (tests/client/blog.spec.js:52:36)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
      at step (tests/client/blog.spec.js:22:191)
      at tests/client/blog.spec.js:22:361
```

Answer (score 1):

You could better check for mock to be called instead of checking your fake `window.location.assign` implementation.

```
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.spyOn(window.location, 'assign').mockImplementation(() => {}) // noop
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    // clean up after all tests
    window.location.assign.mockRestore()
  })

  it('set the DeletePostHandler', async function () {
    // WHEN
    await document.querySelector('#link_1').click();
    // THEN
    expect(mockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(window.location.assign).toBeCalled()
    // or better
    expect(window.location.assign).toBeCalledWith(expectedURL) 
  });
```

Comment: yes, I know that window.location.assign is called  ( in both cases: when Axios resolve() and when Axios reject().. I can check calledWith(url) ... however in this case both urls are identical. That's why I wanted to check with a console log ...  and I am trying to understand how the console.log mocking could work...  the first test is OK but it seems that the console.log mock is not reset... it keeps the same call ( resolved) ... I can give up and stick to what you recommend but my brain was excited by this console.log issue...  :-)

Comment: @erwin There might be other messages printed by the console. Check `console.log.mock.calls.length`. To make your test more robust you could use `expect(console.log).toBeLastCalledWith('resolved')` assertion instead.

Comment: I'll di .. the first test 'resolved' is OK... the issue is that the second test is 'rejected' but I get some issue with the mocks not being reset after each test...

Comment: Weird.. I updated my code and inserted some console.log in the script to be tested ... the first test pass, but not the second test ... I do not understand why the window.location.assign mock is NOT reset before executing the second test....

Comment: As the question becomes unclear ... I'll write another one based only on the the fact that window.location.assign mock function is NOT called when the Axios mock reject ...

Comment: @erwin " I'll write another one based only on the the fact that window.location.assign mock function is NOT called" That would be great :) the amount of code is getting messy :)